# How do I write a Test Class with >80% code coverage for this class that Generates a Service Contract?

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

Here is the Apex Class as written:

```
public class GenerateServiceContract {
    @InvocableMethod(label='GenerateServiceContract' description= 'fetchOrderItems and contractLineItems' category='Order')
    public static void fetchOrderItems(List<Id> orderId) {
        List<Order> relatedOrder = [SELECT Id, 
                                       AccountId,
                                       Account_Name_Text__c,
                                       PriceBook2Id,
                                       EffectiveDate,
                                       EndDate,
                                       End_Date_Year__c,
                                       Order_Name__c,
                                       Existing_Workstream__c,
                                       Existing_License__c,
                                       Workstream_Products_in_this_Order__c,
                                       License_Products_in_this_Order__c,
                                       Specialty__c,
                                       Sub_Specialty__c,
                                       OwnerId,
                                       OpportunityId
                                       FROM Order 
                                       WHERE Id = :orderId];

        ServiceContract scontract = new ServiceContract(
            recordTypeId = '01252000002tSySAAU',
            Related_Order__c = relatedOrder[0].Id,
            Name = relatedOrder[0].Account_Name_Text__c+' - '+relatedOrder[0].Specialty__c+' Contract '+relatedOrder[0].End_Date_Year__c,
            Related_Opportunity__c = relatedOrder[0].OpportunityId,
            StartDate = relatedOrder[0].EffectiveDate,
            EndDate = relatedOrder[0].EndDate,
            End_Date_Year__c = relatedOrder[0]. End_Date_Year__c,
            Workstream_Products_in_this_Contract__c = relatedOrder[0].Workstream_Products_in_this_Order__c,
            License_Products_in_this_Contract__c = relatedOrder[0].License_Products_in_this_Order__c,
            Existing_License__c = relatedOrder[0].Existing_License__c,
            Existing_Workstream__c = relatedOrder[0].Existing_Workstream__c,
            Sub_Specialty__c = relatedOrder[0].Sub_Specialty__c,
            Specialty__c = relatedOrder[0].Specialty__c,
            AccountId = relatedOrder[0].AccountId,
            OwnerId = relatedOrder[0].OwnerId,
            PriceBook2Id = relatedOrder[0].PriceBook2Id
        );
        
            insert scontract;
            List<OrderItem> oproduct = [SELECT Id, PriceBookEntryId, Rev_Recognition_End_Date__c, Rev_Recognition_Start_Date__c, Quantity, UnitPrice, Description FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId = :orderId];
            List<ContractLineItem> citemsToInsert = new List<ContractLineItem>();
            
            for (OrderItem oitem:oproduct) {
                citemsToInsert.add(new ContractLineItem(
                    ServiceContractId = scontract.Id,
                    PriceBookEntryId = oitem.PriceBookEntryId,
                    StartDate = oitem.Rev_Recognition_Start_Date__c,
                    EndDate = oitem.Rev_Recognition_End_Date__c,
                    Description = oitem.Description,
                    Quantity = oitem.Quantity,
                    UnitPrice = oitem.UnitPrice
                ));
            }
            insert citemsToInsert;

        
    }
}
```

Much thanks to Derek F!

```
@IsTest
private class GenerateServiceContract_Test {
    @TestSetup
    static void setup() {
        // Create test data for the Order and OrderItem objects
        Product2 pro = new Product2(Name='Test Product', isActive=true);
        insert pro;
       
        // Instantiate the Pricebook2 record with StandardPricebookId
        Pricebook2 standardPricebook = new Pricebook2(
            Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
            IsActive = true
        );
        // Execute an update DML on the Pricebook2 record, to make IsStandard to true
        Update standardPricebook;
       
        // Query for the Pricebook2 record, to check IsStandard field
        standardPricebook = [SELECT Id, IsStandard FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Id = :standardPricebook.Id LIMIT 1];
        // It should return true
        System.assertEquals(true, standardPricebook.IsStandard);
        
        // Insert PricebookEntry for Standard Price
        insert new PricebookEntry(Product2Id=pro.Id, Pricebook2Id=standardPricebook.Id, UnitPrice=0);
        
        //Insert New Test Pricebook
        Pricebook2 pbt = new Pricebook2(Name='Test Price Book', isActive=true);
        insert pbt;
       
        // Create the new PricebookEntry
        PricebookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = pbt.Id,
            Product2Id = pro.Id,
            UnitPrice = 100,
            IsActive = true,
            UseStandardPrice = false
        );
        insert pbe2;
       
        Account account = new Account(Name='Test Account');
        insert account;
       
        Order order = new Order(AccountId=account.Id, Pricebook2Id=pbt.Id, Status='Draft', EffectiveDate=Date.Today());
        insert order;
       
        OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(OrderId=order.Id, PricebookEntryId=pbe2.id, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=100);
        insert orderItem;
    }

    @IsTest
    static void testFetchOrderItems() {
        // Set up test data
        List<Order> testOrders = [SELECT Id FROM Order];
        List<Id> orderIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Order testOrder : testOrders) {
            orderIds.add(testOrder.Id);
        }

        // Call the method under test
        Test.startTest();
        GenerateServiceContract.fetchOrderItems(orderIds);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Perform assertions
        List<ServiceContract> contracts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ServiceContract];
        System.assertEquals(1, contracts.size(), 'A service contract should be created');
       
        List<ContractLineItem> contractLineItems = [SELECT Id FROM ContractLineItem];
        System.assertEquals(1, contractLineItems.size(), 'Contract line items should be created');
    }
}
```

Comment: Showing us the attempts that you've made at testing this so far would be helpful (and your question will likely be closed without that). You can [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: Aside from that, this sounds like you may not be creating all of the data (that your code needs to run) inside of your test. Tests are isolated from the "real" data in your org by default (and there are very few circumstances where you should breach that isolation). If you have `try`/`catch` in your test(s) to stop exceptions, that also makes it harder for you to see what's going wrong. Also, focus on assertions and having multiple tests to cover different scenarios. If you test enough scenarios, your coverage will naturally be high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard-coding Ids in tests (or in code in general) is usually a red flag. It makes it very difficult to deploy your code between sandboxes (or scratch orgs), or between a sandbox and your production org (though a full/partial copy sandbox *can* smooth things over a bit).

As mentioned in the comments, unit tests do not have access to the data in your org by default (except for a relatively small set of "setup objects" like `User`, `Profile`, `Fieldset`, etc...).

You are responsible for creating the data that your SUT (system under test) needs for it to be able to run. This should be part of the "Arrange" phase of "Arrange, Act, Assert". Setting up test data can be quite tedious because we generally need to set up *the entire hierarchy of SObject records* (e.g. In my org, I need to create 3 Accounts (for a 3-level Account hierarchy), an Asset, several Product2, a Pricebook2, several PricebookEntries, and an Opportunity if I want to test something involving `OpportunityLineItem`) but it is something you need to do.

Comment: Test Gen was sending me down the try / catch path with this attempt.

Comment: @Mark Using TestGen isn't really a substitute for writing proper tests (coverage is meaningless if it allows you to, as an example, deploy a method that says that 2 + 2 = 5). Like I said in my answer, you need to set up _all of the data_ you need. You will need to create an `Order`, an `OrderLineItem`, a `Product2`, a `Pricebook2` (or do a DML update using the standard pricebook id), and a `PricebookEntry` **at the very least**. It's possible that you may need to create more test records in addition to that.

Comment: Thanks Derek! I appreciate the follow up. Is there a good example that shows creating the hierarchy of SObject records in a Test Class?

Comment: Would love your feedback on my updated test class, Derek. Thanks in advance!